# Multiple input in a form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an assign form, for example user select `teacher A` for `subject A` but user can press a button to add more teacher to subject A. I heard this can be done by `Javascript` but I dont know how.

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Teacher</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="teachername">
      <option>Sarah</option>
      <option>Adam</option>
      <option>Mark</option>
      <option>Anderson</option>
      <option>Wood</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-auto p-2">   
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use multi-select or select2 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want user/student A to select multiple teachers for Subject Maths(example), you can use select with checkbox because the user doesn't know how many teachers are available for a particular subject.

Further, you can also implement check/uncheck all functionality

```js
var expanded = false;
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
var inputs = checkboxes.getElementsByTagName('input')


function showCheckboxes() {
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
  const checkboxe = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
  let values = [];
  checkboxe.forEach((checkbox) => {
    values.push(checkbox.value);
  });
  return values;
}

function mySubmitFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('teacher'));
  return false;
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}

.submitBtn {
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction(event)">
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="first">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="first" id="first" />First Teacher</label>
      <label for="second">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="second" id="second" />Second Teacher</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="three" id="three" />Thrid Teacher</label>
      <label for="four">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="four" id="four" />Fourth Teacher</label>
      <label for="five">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="five" id="five" />Fifth Teacher</label>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submitBtn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Will try this one...thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Well.. IDK if this going to make you like it? I'm making the button to add a selected teacher into Array[] call "teachers" then remove selected teacher from options. I hope you can figure the rest?

Here's my example:
https://onecompiler.com/html/3xg4q9e3p

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yours is kinda similar in what I have in mind. Thank you for spending your time to answer this.